# define a struct in iOS6 with ARC

Tags: objective-c, struct, automatic-ref-counting

Simple question: I learned C++ and the syntax of struct. so i want to use structs in my iOS App for Storing data, but ARC does not allowed the usual usage of structs is there any solution for my Problem?

```
struct fruit {
    int a;
};
```

_

```
{
struct fruit apple;
apple.a = 1;
return 0;
}
```

e.g. is it Possible to solve this Problem with an NSMutableArray?
btw where i have to define that? .m file or .h file?

Regards CTS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it is allowed to use structs in Objective-C, even with ARC. There should be absolutely no problem with the struct you specified:

```
struct fruit {
    int a;
};
```

The only problem that occurs with ARC are structs that contain Objective-C objects, because ARC doesn't know how it has to manage those objects. You can however use `__unsafe_unretained`, to let the compiler know that "you know, what you're doing":

```
struct foo {
    __unsafe_unretained NSString *bar;
};
```

`bar` is just a pointer in this case, not a strong reference, managed by ARC. Apple recommends using simple classes in these cases, when possible.